# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: Invalid Value)

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, flutter-getx

When I am fetching data from google drive, I am getting these issues.

Fetching Code:

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [driveScope]);
    googleSignIn.signIn();
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) async {
      var httpClient = await googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();
      var drive = ga.DriveApi(httpClient!);
      await drive.files.list(spaces: 'gdrv').then((value) {
        print('Value = $value');
      });
    });
```

For more information you can check out the below issue image:
[image: Issue image]

Comment: Error code 400 means that you've sent badly formatted or incorrect information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400. I assume you've called a function wrong or something like that, but I can't help much more than that.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the spaces part?